# Using async/await to wait for data to arrive in an array

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, async-await, generator

I want to have two concurrent loops in a modern nodeJS tool.

One loop scans for interesting things and pushes them onto an array.

The second loop shifts things off the array and processes them.

The idea is that the two loops don't block each other. The second loop will be able to catch up on the processing backlog whenever the first loop is doing a lot of scanning but not finding much. Only when there is no backlog and no fresh data coming in will the processing loop have to actually wait.

I've implemented the scanning loop in several ways. It's the easy part. (In this case, I'm recursively scanning the fs looking for files of a certain type.)

For the processing loop, I have it working by polling but feel I should be able to get it working with pure async/await.

But I can't get my head around it. Conceptually the scanning loop should fulfill a promise to alert the second loop there's something in the array, or should be a generator yielding each new value instead of using an array.

But I can't see how to do a promise over and over, or to wait on array activity directly, or to do it as a generator without it causing blocking between the two loops.

I must be overthinking it! What am I missing?

---

**Code working via polling, with commented out bits where an async/await implementation might belong:**

```
"use strict";

const { basename, join } = require('path')

const { promisify } = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir)
const lstat = promisify(fs.lstat)

async function* scanpaths(paths) {
    for (const path of paths) {
        yield* scanonepath(path)
    }
}

async function* scanonepath(path) {
    try {
        const s = await lstat(path)

        if (s.isDirectory()) {
            for (const entry of await readdir(path)) {
                yield* scanonepath(join(path, entry))
            }
        } else if (/\.[mM][pP]3$/.test(path)) {
            yield { pathname:path, basename:basename(path), stat:s }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // special file, deleted file, etc
    }
}

async function* checkqueue(buf) {
    if (buf.length) {
        yield buf.shift()
    } else {
        // TODO await something to arrive in the buf - HOW?
    }
}

async function processmp3(fullname, name, stat) {
    try {
        console.log(fullname)
        // TODO tricky processing goes here
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(name, e)
    }
}

(async () => {
    let int = null
    let globaldone = false
    let globalprocessing = []
    let buf = []

    async function poll() {
        if (buf.length) {
            let clone = Array.from(buf)
            buf.length = 0  // NOT buf = [] as that doesn't change other refs to buf

            for (let e of clone) {
                globalprocessing.push(processmp3(e.pathname, e.basename, e.stat))
            }
        }

        if (globaldone) {
            await Promise.all(globalprocessing)
            console.warn("*** finished processing")
        } else {
            setTimeout(poll, 125)
        }
    }

    // start polling for scanned files ready to process
    console.log("** start polling")
    setTimeout(poll, 0)

    //console.log("** start scanning")
    //await enqueue(buf)

    globaldone = true
    console.warn("*** finished scanning")
})()

// TODO how?
async function enqueue(buf) {
    // start scanning by iterating over our generator which does the recursive directory stuff
    for await (const file of scanpaths(process.argv.slice(2))) {
        buf.push(file)
        // TODO resolve a promise to notify dequeue? or also yield this file
    }
}
```

Comment: `I must be overthinking it!` - yep, too much thinking not enough coding `What am I missing?` ... code?

Comment: I can put the entire code in. I usually find that makes a wall of text that gets a question ignored here...

Comment: So does having no code

Comment: Why not just add an asynchronous action every time something is added to the array? Each process would be separate then.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Well there's the code as it is. Polling works as is. Some confused commented areas are where some possible ways to work without polling might or might now go.

Comment: @PHPglue: That's the approach I tried first. The many simultaneous processing instances blew out memory, so I wanted to introduce a queue in the middle that I would later be able to use to regulate how many items are processed at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Have the scanner loop, when it finds something and pushes it, call a function that tells the processing queue that something was added to the array. If that function is called while the processing queue is actively doing something, do nothing - otherwise, if the processing queue is idle, that'll tell the processing queue to shift an item from the scanning array and process it.

Of course, when the processing queue is finished processing an item, have it check to see if there are additional items to be processed, and if there are, process the next one immediately. This ensures that the processing queue will only be idle when there are no more items to process, and it'll start running again as soon as a new item gets pushed.

For example, with your code, you could do something like this instead:

```
let processing = false;
async function processNext() {
  if (processing) {
    return;
  }
  processing = true;
  const e = buf.shift();
  const mp3 = await processmp3(e.pathname, e.basename, e.stat);
  // do something with parsed mp3?
  processing = false;
  processNext();
}


async function enqueue(buf) {
  for await (const file of scanpaths(process.argv.slice(2))) {
    buf.push(file);
    processNext();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to call a function that tells the processing queue something. How would that work?

Comment: That's what the `processNext` function does in the code in the answer - if you call it, and nothing is being processed, it'll start processing the next item.

Comment: Ah my Wi-Fi died while the answer came in. Just finally got it working again. Will take a look and get back to you. Thanks.